# Dynamically change filter for logback appender?

Tags: logging, logback

I'd like to be able to dynamically change the filter level for a single appender in logback

For example if I have

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%X{traceId}] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %marker - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Root Config -->
<root level="${log_level:-INFO}">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-SERVICE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

How can I at runtime change the STDOUT appender to allow debug vs info?

I can change globally the root level easily:

```
def setLogLevel(value: Level, loggerName: String = org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME) = {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName).asInstanceOf[Logger]

  logger.setLevel(LogbackLevel.valueOf(value.toString))
}
```

But I'd really like to have control on which appender gets which level dynamically.

I tried manipulating level filters on the appenders but that didn't seem to do much

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am sitting with the same issue. I want to have the root logger level to be permissive, e.g. TRACE, then per appender, control what level is logged. I've tried clearing and adding the filters on the appender again but it does not work.

Comment: @Will777 see my answer

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was having the root level always log at Debug and provide threshold filters for each appender:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
     <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%X{traceId}] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %marker - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Root Config -->
<root level="${log_level:-DEBUG}">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-SERVICE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Then I used the ConfigurationDelegate class from the groovy logback api to query the appenders

```
 val context = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory.asInstanceOf[LoggerContext] 

 val configuration = {
    val delegate = new ConfigurationDelegate
    delegate.setContext(context)
    delegate
  }

  /**
   * Sets the log level for a particular appender
   * @param value
   * @param appenderName
   */
  def setAppenderLevel(value: Level, appenderName: String) = {
    appenders.find(_.getName == appenderName) match {
      case Some(appender) =>
        val filters = appender.getCopyOfAttachedFiltersList

        filters.find(_.isInstanceOf[ThresholdFilter]).foreach(m => m.asInstanceOf[ThresholdFilter].setLevel(value.toString))
      case None =>
    }
  }
```

And I looked for the threshhold filter and set the value by hand.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for posting! I started messing around with this last night, I went the same route - I couldn't figure out how to get the current set of filters on each appender - your post helps a lot. I went with LevelFilters instead of ThresholdFilters. My initial problem was that you have to invoke start() on the filter, else it doesn't take effect.